# What is the significance of the vector dimension in semidefinite programming relaxations?

Tags: optimization, approximation, max-cut

Let's say that we want to design a semi-definite programming approximation for an optimization problem such as MAX-CUT or MAX-SAT or what have you.

So, we first write down an integer quadratic program that solves the problem exactly. For example, in the case of MAX-CUT we would write:
$$
\max \sum_{\{u,v\} \in E}{\frac{1 - x_u x_v}{2}}
$$
$$
x_v \in \{-1,+1\}.
$$

Then we relax the program by allowing the variables to take on vector values in the sphere $S^{n-1}$, and replacing products with scalar products, obtaining a semi-definite program that can be solved precisely.

Our approximation proceeds by solving the SDP and rounding the solution to obtain a legal solution for the original problem whose distance from the SDP solution can be bounded.

My question is: **What is the importance of the dimension of the vectors?** In all the cases I have seen, the analysis would stay the same if we assume that the vectors are all unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$. So why do people always take vectors in $S^{n-1}$?

Comment: (1) The reduction of the relaxation to SDP requires that the vectors be in R^n (if you restrict the vectors to a smaller space you don't get an SDP).  (2) I believe (?) that, if you constrain the vectors to a space smaller than R^(n-1), then the relaxation can give you a better approximation ratio, and (in general) remains NP-hard.

Comment: @NealYoung: Turn into an answer?

Comment: Essentially the same question is asked in this later post: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/why-the-goemans-williamsons-max-cut-algorithm-relax-the-variables-to-vectors-of?noredirect=1#comment184545_86043

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vector programs are solved by solving semidefinite programs. The basic idea is that if $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are vectors, then the matrix $V_{ij} = \langle v_i,v_j \rangle$ is positive semidefinite:
$$ \alpha' V \alpha = \sum_{i,j} \alpha_i \alpha_j \langle v_i, v_j \rangle = \left\|\sum_i \alpha_i v_i\right\|^2. $$
The converse is also true: a positive semidefinite $n \times n$ matrix $V$ of rank $r$ can be written as $V = LL'$, where $L$ is $n \times r$ (this is known as the [Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition)). Furthermore, $L$ can be found effectively given $V$. If $\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_n$ are the $r$-dimensional rows of $L$, then $V_{ij} = \ell_i \ell'_j = \langle \ell_i, \ell_j \rangle$. We can therefore optimize a vector program involving inner products of vectors $v_i$ by solving a semidefinite program. Rank constraints are not convex, and so we cannot really control the dimension of the vectors other than the trivial bound $n$.

As you mention, the analysis in the particular case of MAX-CUT only uses the two-dimensional projections. This shows that even if you could somehow guarantee that $\operatorname{rank} V = 2$ (recall that the rank corresponds to the dimension), the analysis wouldn't get better. On the other hand, if you could guarantee than $\operatorname{rank} V = 1$, you will have solved MAX-CUT exactly. This shows that the latter constraint is NP-hard to realize. It is probably the case that any non-trivial rank constraint cannot be enforced in polynomial time, and any constant rank constraint is NP-hard.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot/ didn't understand the significance of the fact that we solve vector programs like the above via optimization over a positive semidefinite matrix and then performing a Cholesky decomposition.